# Must i resolve warnings which just show in local host or ignore them?

Tags: next.js, hydration

I have some warnings such as hydration warnings in nextJs, which just show in my local host and every thing is ok in stage and production .

I've tried to solve hydration warnings before but because of using random values in some cards get this type of warning again, considering they are generating just in local host can i ignore and do nothing with them?
and why they are in local host console but aren't in stage and production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next.js hydration errors are caused by a mis-matched DOM. There a few ways you can go about fixing it:

## Check your HTML markup

A lot of times a persistent hydration error is caused by invalid HTML. Just double just your HTML is semitic.

From the official Next.js docs:

> Incorrect nesting of HTML tags
>
> nested in another
>
> tag
>  nested in a
>
> tag
>  or  nested in a
>
> tag
> Interactive Content cannot be nested ( nested in a  tag,  > nested in a  tag, etc)

## Using browser only apis in server components

Browser only apis like `window` should be avoided in Next.js. However, if you must use them they need to be inside a client component with `useEffect`.

## Browser extensions

Try running the project in a private window with no extensions and see if the issue is resolved. Certain extensions may cause this error.

## CSS in JS libraries

These are only supported in client components

## IOS with safari bugs:

From the Next.js docs:

> OS attempts to detect phone numbers, email addresses, and other data in text content and convert them into links, leading to hydration mismatches.
> This can be disabled with the following meta tag:

```
<meta
  name="format-detection"
  content="telephone=no, date=no, email=no, address=no"/>
```

## Suppress the hydration error (last resort)

Simply add the suppress hydration error on anyone of your components. Just add the `<MyComponent suppressHydrationWarning />`.

## Conclusion and additional resources

It's recommended my to try all the above fixes before suppressing or ignoring the error as it does impact performance.

For more information visit the [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error).

Comment: thanx a lot, so it's better to fix these warnings and get no warning in console of local host,  right?

Comment: @farzaneh Yes. Since this error does impact performance.